Differences in Landau/Lifshitz Volume 1 editions
I can't seem to find any relevant information about the sections that are altered between editions of Landau/Lifshitz, specifically the first volume.
I'm a big sucker for nice books (collector!), and I can only find the first edition in hardcover (for a reasonable price), so I'm thinking of purchasing that; note that I will also be using it for a course, so I'm not just collecting it.
If anyone has any information about what's different between the first and third edition of Mechanics (and also maybe the second volume, on classical field theories), I'd greatly appreciate it.

Hi trashpew. Welcome to Phys.SE. I removed the shopping advice subquestion as it is off-topic.

The preface to the second English edition states:

No extensive revision of the book has been necessary for the second English edition. A few additional comments and problems have been inserted in various places, and a number of errors have been corrected.

In the preface to the third English edition, E. M. Lifshitz states:

... the present volume 1 has not required any considerable revision, as is to be expected in such a well-established branch of theoretical physics as mechanics is. Only the final sections, on adiabatic invariants, have been revised by L. P. Pitaevskii and myself.
...
The present edition contains the biography of Landau which I wrote in 1969 for the posthumous Russian edition of his Collected Works. I should like to hope that it will give the reader some slight idea of the personality of that remarkable man.

In other words, the editions are not substantially different from each other.
